# Android Universal Music Player unable to advance to next or other song while playing to Chromecast Audio

Tags: android, chromecast, android-music-player

I'm trying to learn this Universal Music Player sample for my own app development. I was never expecting this so haven't even tried it out so far, but the sample from the GitHub behaves oddly when streaming to Chromecast Audio. I haven't found any related info anywhere, so have been posting this question wherever I can, hoping to get some hints from those of you with some experience with UAMP.

When I'm playing a song on the json list (from the default Google server) to Chromecast Audio and select another song on the list or try to skip to the next song, an error is thrown (see log below) about 5 times and it doesn't progress to the next or selected song. Instead it just moves on to a random song on the list, or keeps playing the same song. This is with the GitHub code directly complied and run on a tablet, without any modification. This does not happen when Chromecast is not being used (i.e., playing directly on the tablet). Sorry about the messy log message. Hope someone has some experience / knowledge on this and can give me a hint!

---

```
11-15 03:08:49.792 18204-18204/com.example.android.uamp 
E/MediaNotificationServiceImpl: Unregistering trampoline BroadcastReceiver failed
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: yy@8f7a15d
at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:789)
at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1200)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:576)
at yx.b(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC@11746440:105)
at yp.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC@11746440:22)
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:392)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzed.zzb(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.zze.onDestroy(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.MediaNotificationService.onDestroy(Unknown Source)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopService(ActivityThread.java:3244)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap21(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1591)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
```

Answer (score 0):

I initially reported this on GitHub, and while waiting found a workaround, described here:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer/issues/182

It's basically tweaking CastPlayback.java a bit so that the playback method doesn't get called multiple times with changing media info.